# Processing from foreignkey table fields while creating multiple objects in django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Models.py

```
class Season(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     statuses = models.CharField()

class Match(models.Model):
     SHOT_CHOICES = (
     ('W', 'Win'),
     ('F', 'Fail'),
     ('D', 'Draw'),
     )
     season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     status = models.CharField(choices=STAT_CHOICE, max_length=1)
```

My view for creating matches

```
class CreateMatches(generics.CreateApiView)
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
             self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
```

statuses is a string like "WFFWFDDW", I need to fetch "nth" character from the foreign key season's statuses to status of "nth" match.

Comment: Does your **`status`** field of `Match` model depends on any input data from `request` ?

Comment: @JPG it doesn't depend on request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `status` field of **`Match`** model not depends on any input data from request, you could save the last char by overriding the **`save()`** method of **`Match`** model. But, you have to set **`null=True`**

```
class Match(models.Model):
    SHOT_CHOICES = (
        ('W', 'Win'),
        ('F', 'Fail'),
        ('D', 'Draw'),
    )
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STAT_CHOICE, max_length=1, null=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.status = self.season.statuses[-1]

        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: @Jiss Raphel Are you sure the suggested edit is required?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by overriding the perform_create function

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if type(serializer.validated_data) == list:
        for iter,item in enumerate(serializer.validated_data):
            season = item['season']
            count = season.matches.count()
            status = season.statuses[count+iter]
            item.update({'status':status})
        serializer.save()
```